# Is this an issue with the server code, or the app code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When rendering my app on the server I get and Invariant error with the provider element. Error is `Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.` I also get this warning `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop`children`of type`array`supplied to Provider, expected a single ReactElement. in Provider`

```
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const provider = react.createElement(Provider, { store: store }, RouterContext);
const ReactApp = renderToString(provider);

const reactRouter = require('react-router');
const RouterContext = reactRouter.RouterContext;
```

Comment: Something wrong with the `RouterContext`, can you show us how you made this `RouterContext`

Comment: @DavidGuan I updated my question with the last two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Provider>` component accepts only a single element as its children. You can change your code to pass an element, not an array:

```
const RouterContext = react.createElement(reactRouter.RouterContext, renderProps);
const provider = react.createElement(Provider, { store: store }, RouterContext);
```

Comment: where exactly is `renderProps` defined?

Comment: I think the above code is for server side rendering and you should use `match()` function to find a matching route and render a correct component. The `match()` function takes a callback as a second argument, where the third argument is `renderProps`.